# Can you easily get between Rotterdam Central Station and Rotterdam The Hague Airport by public transport?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, netherlands, rotterdam, rtm

In the past when I've gone to Rotterdam, it has either been by train, or from the [port](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13900/best-way-from-central-rotterdam-to-europoort), which we've got [questions covering](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17580/other-public-transport-from-rotterdam-central-station-to-europort). This time, having snagged a very good deal, I'll be flying into Rotterdam The Hague Airport, which is a first for me.

Is it easy to get from the airport to near Rotterdam Central Station by public transport, or would it involve walking/changes/taxis/etc.? And if it is possible by public transport, is it for normal local prices, or does it end up requiring [special expensive tickets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12766/why-is-public-transport-from-to-the-airport-so-expensive) for the journey?

Comment: -1: This is very easy to find online.

Comment: @Bernhard So what? Shall we now downvote your answer because it is easy to find?

Comment: @MarcelC. Hovering the downvote reads "Does not show any research effort", in my opinion that is appropriate. I always leave a comment when I downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Bernhard](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/18469/26) managed to find, there's information on public transport on the [airport's website](http://www.rotterdamthehagueairport.nl/en/Openbaar_vervoer) (click the British flag in the top bar if it comes up in Dutch). It's actually even easier than the website makes out!

In the baggage hall, there's a sign up explaining about the two bus options, and with directions to the bus stops. When you exit the terminal, turn left and walk for an epic 20-30 meters, and you'll reach the bus stops. There's one stop for the #50, one for the #33, both well signed. If you have an [OV-chipcard](https://www.ov-chipkaart.nl/?taal=en), you can use that for the journey. Otherwise, €3 in cash paid onboard gets your a single ticket valid for 1 hour.

The [#33 bus](http://www.ret.nl/en/nc/travel-with-ret/timetable/details/bus/lijn-33/heen.html) runs direct to Rotterdam Central Station, taking about 25-30 minutes. For the west of the city centre or around the station, that's probably the best bet. Otherwise, the [#50](http://www.ret.nl/en/nc/travel-with-ret/timetable/details/bus/lijn-50.html) bus shuttles you out to the Meijersplein metro station, from which it's easy to take the metro north to The Hague (Den Haag), or south into the city centre. You can use a journey planner like the [Rome2Rio one](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Rotterdam-Airport-RTM-Netherlands/Rotterdam) or [Ret.nl](http://www.ret.nl/en/travel-with-ret/travel-planner.html) to work out which'll be the best for you. Both buses are pretty frequent, every 10-20 minutes depending on the time of day, and you can be at the bus stop in well under 10 minutes from wheels down if you're travelling only with hand luggage only

Depending on how many journeys you plan to take, it might or might not be worth getting an OV-chipkaart. It's currently [€7.50 for one](https://www.ov-chipkaart.nl/aanvragen/), which reduces the single ticket to the city centre to €1.66, so you'll need to make a few journeys to make it worthwhile. If it's open, you can buy one from the [Ako newsagent](http://www.rotterdamthehagueairport.nl/Openbaar_vervoer), which is between the arrivals and departure areas (turn right outside customs, and it's on your left next to the currency exchange office). However, Ako seems to have much shorter opening hours than many other places in the airport, so take care if arriving very early or late in the day! Otherwise, the people at the information desk just after you exit customs are very helpful, ask them for advice if you need it!

Comment: Good to know all worked out well. As you can read in the edit I made to Bernhards answer you can buy the OV card at the airport from a shop named "Ako".

Comment: I'll have a look for that shop tonight!

Comment: @BartArondson Ako is a newsagents between the arrivals and departures area (see updated answer), but people need to take care as it was the only place closed tonight, so it seems to keep much shorter hours than the rest of the airport does!

Answer (score 5):

The website of [Rotterdam-The Hague airport](http://www.rotterdamthehagueairport.nl/Openbaar_vervoer) is pretty clear. According to the timetable, bus 33 is leaving every 20 minutes from the airport, to bring you to the central station in just over 20 minutes.

According to the most general [Dutch website on public transport](http://9292.nl/en/journeyadvice/rotterdam_luchthaven-rotterdam-the-hague-airport/station-rotterdam-centraal/departure/2013-06-27T2007#), you'll pay €1.66 for a one-way trip if you use the OV-card. The [public transport section of the airport website](http://www.rotterdamthehagueairport.nl/Openbaar_vervoer) states that this card can be bought from a shop named "Ako". It will cost you €7.50 for the card only, and you have to charge it with a minimum of €5 before you can use it.
Alternatively you can buy a paper one-way ticket from the driver for €3, according to [this website](http://www.vliegveldinfo.nl/vliegvelden/rotterdam-the-hague-airport/).